# Real Part with Singular Values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**[Ciarlet 1.2-4]** Lea $A$ a real matrix of order $n$. Show that a necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of a unitary matrix $U$ of the same order and of a real matrix $B$ (of the same order) such that $U = A + iB$ (in other words, such that the matrix $A$ is the 'real part' of the matrix $U$) is that all the singular values of the matrix $A$ should be not greater than 1.

Comment: What is the full title of the book authored by Ciarlet?

Comment: "Introduction to numerical linear algebra and optimisation" by Philippe G. Ciarlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:** Let $U=A+iB$. Then
\begin{align*}
&U \text{ is unitary }\\
\Leftrightarrow &I = U^\ast U = (A^T-iB^T)(A+iB) = A^TA + B^TB + i(A^TB-B^TA)\\
\Leftrightarrow &A^TA + B^TB = I \text{ and } A^TB-B^TA=0.
\end{align*}
Now, consider a pair of left, right singular vectors $u$ and $v$ corresponding to the singular value $\sigma$ of $A$, so that $Av=\sigma u$ and $\|u\|=\|v\|=1$. If $\sigma\neq0$, by considering $v^TA^TAv$, show that if $A^TA + B^TB = I$, we must have $\sigma\le1$.

Conversely, suppose all singular values of $A$ are $\le1$. Let $A=USV^T$ be a singular value decomposition, where $U,V$ are real orthogonal and $S$ is the diagonal matrix containing the singular values of $A$. Consider a matrix of the form $B=UDV^T$. Express $A^TA + B^TB$ and $A^TB-B^TA$ in terms of $V,S$ and $D$. Can you find a **real diagonal** matrix $D$ such that $A^TA + B^TB = I$ and $A^TB-B^TA=0$?

Comment: I understand the hints, but Can you spell out all the proof?

Comment: @FASCH I would like you to ponder the solution more first. I have added some more details to the hints. If you still get stuck, tell me where the difficulty is and I'll see what I can help.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for this. The first hints that you gave to me, I knew it. Now I am going to try again with this new hints. Thanks

Comment: user1551, thanks so much. I could solve the problem with your hints.