# Who introduced the term "norm" into mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, math-history

I've always been curious about the motivation behind the use of the word [norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_norm), as used in linear algebra and functional analysis, for a function that assigns a positive number to a vector.

Who introduced this term into mathematics?

Comment: I guess the world itself looks a bit weird if you forget all the times we've used it in math, it's not really suggestive.

Comment: Was it George Wendt?

Comment: I think it comes from normal as questions about objects being normal to a plane or a line occurred in mathematics far before abstract norms were created. Though this is pure conjecture.

Comment: Norman Vector Peale, in his book, "The Power of Positive Metrics."

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=norm) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel_square#Carpenter.27s_square) are related (to the question).

Comment: I wonder if it's related to the term "normal" (as in perpendicular).

Comment: Could be related to the fact that the length of a vector has components that are normal to each other and the length is computed using these "normal" components

Comment: Also possibly of interest: [Etymology of the word “normal” (perpendicular)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328662/etymology-of-the-word-normal-perpendicular).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have personal insight into this question, but I do have Google! According to [Steven Schwartzman's *The Words of Mathematics*](http://books.google.com/books?id=SRw4PevE4zUC&pg=PA146), "norm" derives from the Latin *norma* meaning "carpenter's square", which explains its meaning of perpendicularity and measuring a unit. According to [Jeff Miller's *Earliest Known Uses of
Some of the Words of Mathematics*](http://jeff560.tripod.com/n.html), "norm" was first used in number theory by Gauss in 1832, for the Gaussian integers. From there, it was imported into analysis by Albert A. Bennett in 1921 and by Banach in 1922.