# What does the word "norm" stands for in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

I know that "norm" is the formal name for length, but where did this name came from? or from what language is came from?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hamilton apparently used it in 1856 for complex numbers.

Comment: As usual, see the entry in Jeff Miller's [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics](http://jeff560.tripod.com/mathword.html).

Comment: Largely duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465414/who-introduced-the-term-norm-into-mathematics).

Answer (score 4):

It is derived from the Latin word *norma*, which means rule or standard. ‘Ruler’ — a straight stick that measures length — has the same origin, which is pretty much the same as what a norm does in mathematics.

Comment: I agree that is the etymology of "norm" in its ordinary English usage. But how did it come to be used in maths?