# Notion of a normal operator

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, representation-theory

I understand that a normal operator is an operator such that

$$
AA^\dagger = A^\dagger A
$$
where $\dagger$ is the conjugate transpose.

However, what is the most intuitive way to "characterise" this? For example,

1. $SO(3)$ is the group of rotations in $\mathbb R^3$
2. A unitary matrix is one that represents an isometry
3. A hermitian matrix is a generalization of symmetric, and is the "nicest" (diagonalizable, real eigenvalues, etc) of all matrices over $\mathbb C$

I was hoping for some sort of intuitive explanation of why I would care about normal matrices over $\mathbb C$ (maybe other reasons than the spectral theorem? Something more fundamental / geometric perhaps)

Comment: Normal operators are the ones which can be diagonalized via an unitary. In this case they behave like finite sequences of numbers (namely, the diagonal), and they have very well-behaved analytical properties.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro - so the reason I would choose to care is because there's a unitary change of basis that makes them diagonalizable?

Comment: Yes. Moreover, since an unitary change of basis preserves the inner product, the geometry of the vector space is also unchanged, which can be quite useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The term *"normal"* here refers to orthogonality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328662/etymology-of-the-word-normal-perpendicular). Geometrically, a normal operator on $\mathbb C^n$ represents scaling by possibly different (complex) factors along different axes of an orthogonal coordinate frame. This, I think, is more intuitive than a Hermitian operator (which, of course, is also normal).

Comment: A Hermitian operator is simply a normal operator with real eigenvalues (scaling factors).

Comment: @celtschk LOL. Of course you are right.

Answer (score 4):

A square complex matrix $A$ is normal iff it has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. That's why you would care about it. Unitary and selfadjoint matrices are special cases. Normal is the most general case.